# append string after each line from pipe line

Tags: bash

the following script.bin append by tee  lines to file.log (from my bash script)

```
  IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  ./script.bin | tee -a file.log
```

my target is to add the "IP=127.0.0.1" after each line that created by tee
(the IP address is example)

remark: we can't  modify the script.bin in order to add the "IP=127.0.0.1" -because its binary file

I need advice how we can to add IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx after each line that created in file.log

Jon

```
cat file.log (the ordinary file.log)

start_listen_to_port - 5500
start_listen_to_port - 5400
start_listen_to_port - 5410
.
.
.





cat file.log ( the right log.file syntax )

start_listen_to_port - 5500 IP=127.0.0.1
start_listen_to_port - 5400 IP=127.0.0.1
start_listen_to_port - 5410 IP=127.0.0.1
.
.
.
```

Comment: I need advice how we can to add IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx after each line that created in file.log

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
./script.bin | sed "s/\$/ IP=$IP/" | tee -a file.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it through sed first to replace end-of-line with the ip

```
./script.bin | sed 's/$/ IP=127.0.0.1/' | tee...
```